# Converting a SAS date in scala

Tags: scala, date, sas

I have a text file that has SAS date format date in it. Now, I need to load this file into a table in Hive using Scala.

SAS date : 21558
Expected output : 2019-01-09

Could you please help me out with the correct command to get this output

Comment: What have you already tried by yourself?

Comment: Figure out how to represent the first day in 1960 as a date. Then figure out how to add the number of days in your variable from SAS to get the date you want.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know what SAS is, or what the "date" 21558 is supposed to represent. So I did some "internet" searching and found that a SAS date is the number of days since Jan. 1st, 1960.

Hmmmm....

```
import java.time.{Month, LocalDate}
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit.DAYS

val sasStart = LocalDate.of(1960, Month.JANUARY, 1)

sasStart.plus(21558, DAYS).toString
//res0: String = 2019-01-09
```

This "internet" thing just might catch on.